# Running tomcat under tomcat service account in CentOS

Tags: centos, non-root-user, tomcat

I'm installing tomcat on a CentOS box for use as an application server. My system admin created a tomcat user service account under which to run tomcat. I'm generally following instructions on [this page](http://www.davidghedini.com/pg/entry/install_tomcat_7_on_centos) but when I get to the step where I adjust the startup script to  run the tomcat startup and shutdown commands as user tomcat (Step 6, item 4) I'm being asked for a password for the tomcat account. Since this is a service account should I be able to `/bin/su tomcat` to run certain commands as the tomcat user without entering the password?

I'm generally unfamiliar with setting up tomcat to run under a service account. If anyone has best practices for this please let me know.

**Update**: I found a good article covering installing tomcat as a service under a low privilege user [here](http://www.mulesoft.com/tcat/tomcat-on-linux-installation-and-configuration). Following that article I eventually got my installation working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not logged in/elevated as root, and are a "regular" user, you will need to provide the password for another user account.

However, you may want to look into `sudo` to achieve what you are trying accomplish. You will likely need to consult with your sysadmin to properly set you up in the `sudoers` file in order to grant you the access you require.

Comment: My user account is granted sudo rights but when I use sudo to run the startup script I get the message: "This account is currently not available."

Comment: That's normally due to a lack of a shell specified for the user account. Sometimes sysadmins do that for security purposes.

Answer (score 0):

No service accounts such as this are typically not configured to be logged into. You can see this if you look at the file `/etc/passwd`. You can also see it using the `getent` command.

#### Example

```
$ getent passwd saml
saml:x:1000:1000:saml:/home/saml:/bin/bash
```

Notice that my account is setup to use a shell, `/bin/bash`. Meanwhile a service account is not.

```
$ getent passwd nginx
nginx:x:987:978:Nginx web server:/var/lib/nginx:/sbin/nologin
```

To make changes to any files related to this service you'll need to use `sudo` privileges to edit them. Simply doing a `sudo vim </path/to/file>` will allow you to edit them preserving the original user of these files.

If you need to make new files, you'll need to take care to `chown <user>.<group>` new files to the service account and its default Unix group as well.

Comment: I wasn't actually trying to login to this account...just trying to run commands as this user which I should be able to do.

Comment: @Tom - you can run commands as a user via sudo as well: `sudo -u tomcat <cmd>`.